# Can't find a VLAN connection on network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

So, I'm at Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, and I created a VLAN connection through the following button (Networking / [+] / VLAN) :

[image: Creating a VLAN]

It becomes created, and a new interface appears as shown by the 'ip link' command, but then I cannot find it anywhere to delete it.

```
ivila@ivila-ThinkPad:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:ee:75:0f:30:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:2a:ea:15:6f:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:be:3c:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: enx98ded004c00d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:de:d0:04:c0:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
**11: enx98ded004c0.0@enx98ded004c00d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:de:d0:04:c0:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff**
```

I can erase it using the same command ( ip link delete enx98ded004c0.0@enx98ded004c00d), but whenever i change anything related to the network configuration, it is again created.

How can I delete it completely? 
Where is it at the network configuration window?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed it to erase it through the network manager terminal util:

nmcli c -> Show connections 
nmcli c delete "VLAN Connection 1"

It's not really an answer, but it works.